# Force office addin to open link in embedded browser

Tags: javascript, office-addins

My excel addin is hosting on a private endpoint. After user open addin bar, app is redirected to the login page, which doesn't excel addin app (window.Office is not provided) after a user clicks any link or button which changes window.location.href, default browser will be opened.
I need a way to change location inside of addin. Stange fact, on one machine behavior is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. I've just added AppDomains into manifest.xml and it works well.